# Typedef mutually referenced stl container

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl

I have a `std::map` and a `std::list`. I want the elements in the containers to have the type of the iterator of opposite container.

How can I typedef them?

**Example:**

```
 typedef std::map<MyKeyClass, typename MyList::iterator> MyMap;
 //                                    ^ MyList not defined.
 typedef std::list<typename MyMap::iterator> MyList;
```

Of course inverting the two lines doesn't work.

I also tried

```
 typedef std::map<MyKeyClass,
                  typename std::list<typename MyMap::iterator>::iterator> MyMap;
 typedef std::list<typename MyMap::iterator> MyList;
```

but that did not work either.

**UPDATE:**
The reason I need this is to keep track key/value pairs by 2 aspect of  orders. Let's say that I have a `map<KEY,VALUE>`. It is sorted by KEY and find a value by a key is fast. But I also want to keep track the values by the time when the value is added. I want to know which value is least recently added. To do this I use list. The reason I need an iterator back to the list from the map is to erase an element in the containers. When I erase an element in the map by a key, I also need to erase an element in the list. I also need the opposite (erasing the least recently value).
I found that my idea that to use pointers explicitly (as in the comments) does not work because I need actually an iterator to erase an element in the containers.

**UPDATE2:**
I'm asking this because I felt a little weird that I can not do this. I often use STL container as a basic data structure (as everyone does). For example, `std::map` can be used as alternative to implementation of binary tree with explicit struct and pointers. STL containers are well designed and I have not experienced that I can not use STL container to express some structure that can be done by struct and pointers. They may not guarantee that STL container has same property as struct and pointer structure have. But still, with such simple structure I felt a little strange I can not express it with STL containers.

Comment: This is like `struct X { Y y; }; struct Y { X x; };`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but in that case we can use forward declaration. How can I do it with my example?
UPDATE:Sorry it can not be done by forward declaration because its not pointer. I use iterator as kind of pointer here. So what I want to do is something like forward declaration for iterator... May not be possible thought.

Comment: You have no control about the interna of the standard library containers, so you cannot assert that "it's like pointer". The standard says that the types must be complete, period.

Comment: @ShuSuzuki -- in the case of `X { Y y; }; struct Y { X x; };` you canNOT forward declare X or Y -- as the requirement is that they are complete types as well.   Forward declarations gives incomplete types which can only be used for pointer declarations.

Comment: @Kerrek Yea I know. I wondered if there is some work around for this problem. Using pointers to variables in the containers explicitly may be one possible solution. But I still could not have confident that this is only thing we can do.

Comment: @Soren Yea I misunderstood the code. That's what I commented as `UPDATE` in previous comment.

Comment: Ugly workaround: Store Boost.Any objects in the containers. This will incur extra run-time overhead for type checking, but at least it's straightforward and doesn't require messing around with pointers.

Comment: maybe [vector-of-derived-classes](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19275/vector-of-derived-classes), [vector of different types](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=30&ved=0CGMQFjAJOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fcpp_questions%2Fcomments%2F1w5uqf%2Fbest_way_to_have_a_vector_of_different_types%2F&ei=o63KU6_oNuX9ygOi3oCgAw&usg=AFQjCNHacb-Bp-Uo4tINsmYYyIRuPLWl1g&sig2=e18FgxJ55V_nMLzWnnEelg&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGQ&cad=rja) or [STL typedefs and incomplete types](http://www.mofeel.net/1095-comp-lang-c++-moderated/7367.aspx) could be of interest for you

Comment: The answer is: no, it's not possible. Instead, what are you trying to do? (that is, what is your problem, and "a bigger picture")

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a multi-index container, as the one found in boost. It allows you to have maps / sets sorted and accessible by multiple key types.

Boost bimap is a similar tool, with only two keys/ indices,  essentially allowing you to access a map by both key and value.

Comment: +1: Boost Multi-index and bimap also provide support for "chronological order" as an index (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/, check the example)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible because it creates an endless recursive definition.

Consider what happens in your first typedef, on the second example:

```
typedef std::map<MyKeyClass,
    typename std::list<typename MyMap::iterator>::iterator> MyMap;
```

The MyMap inside would be expanded, and you would get

```
typedef std::map<MyKeyClass,
    typename std::list<typename std::map<MyKeyClass,
        typename std::list<typename MyMap::iterator>::iterator>::iterator>::iterator> MyMap;
```

And then there would be another MyMap there to expand.
Now you can see where this is going. You should consider what you're trying to do and see if there isn't a better way of modeling your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could wonder why you need that ciclic types is because the map stores references to lists, and the lists store references to the map. In other words, **you want to share data between the map and the lists**. Use a map of `std::shared_ptr`s, and a lists of `std::shared_ptr`s, which allows you to easy share the elements (Which are the true data) between maps and lists.

Comment: I updated the question. Yes I want to share data between the map and the list. (In my updated question case VALUE is shared.) . But I still wonder how I can erase an element in the containers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

After all I wrote the code below. It is compiled by g++.

```
struct ListEntry;
typedef std::unordered_map<MyKeyClass, typename std::list<ListEntry>::iterator> KeyMap;
struct ListEntry{
   typename KeyMap::iterator it;                                                       
};
typedef std::list<ListEntry> MyList;
```